# Tell gnu-autotools where my newly installed library is (with PKG_CONFIG?)

Tags: c++, ios, c, autotools

Sorry, my gnu-autotools Fu is rusty here . .

Our application uses 'packs' - GBs of data that is downloaded by the user and demand. To test this, I would like to use libifuse to transfer data to/from the iOS device without jail-breaking. So, I'm building libifuse from source, starting with dependencies:

**I installed libusbmuxd:**

It installed to the following:

```
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c iproxy '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/iproxy /usr/local/bin/iproxy
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libusbmuxd.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
```

**Can't build libimobiledevice - need to find libusbmuxd:**

Now when building libimobiledevice, I get the following error, when running ./configure:

```
checking for libusbmuxd... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libusbmuxd >= 1.0.8) were not met:

No package 'libusbmuxd' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libusbmuxd_CFLAGS
```

**My Question:**

How do I tell the `gnu-autotools` where my newly installed library is? What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the package `pkg-config`.

In fact, the autotools use `pkg-config` to see if the package you need is installed.

Edit:

Try `pkg-config --print-variables libusbmuxd` to see if you got something.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a good error message telling me what I need to do: "Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusbmuxd.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable"

Comment: See my edit. The autotools use something like `pkg-config --exists libusbmuxd` to see if your lib is installed.